# Iterating through two arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that I load data from a server into an `NSArray` and then into `UITableView`.

This works fine. However, when the user pulls down to refresh the data, I make a new call to my server and grab data again. This new data contains objects that my local data already has and any new objects.

So `localArray` when populated for the first time will have objects, `[A,B,C,D]`. I then add a new object server side and refresh the data on the iOS app.

`serverData` will now have objects `[A,B,C,D,E,F]` - I need to add, `E,F` to `localArray`.

I thought a nested for loop would be the answer, something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *newItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (BBItem *itemA in serverDataArray){
    for (BBItem *itemB in localArray){
        if (![itemA.name isEqualToString:itemb.named]){
                //add to a newItems array
        }
    }
}
```

However I end up with newItems array containing a lot of duplicates of the same item. What is going on here?

Comment: Is `isEqualToString:itemb.named` instead of `isEqualToString:itemb.name` a typo?

Comment: You're adding itemA to the array for every itemB that isn't the same.

Comment: You're adding all the items over and over again.  You need to see if localArray contains each item on the server array.  You are checking every combination and adding those that don't match.  If local = @[a, b, c] and server contains @[b, c, d], your new items array will be @[b, b, c, c, d, d, d]. Step through your code in the debugger and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka A typo. wottle = thank you for explaining the error of my code. It helps clear things up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm will add an item to `newItems` if it's not equal to one item from `localArray`. Therefore, you would end up with lots of identical items most of the time.

You cannot add inside the nested loop. You need to go through all `localArray`, see that the item is not there, and only then add it. Here is how to fix your code:

```
for (BBItem *itemA in serverDataArray){
    BOOL there = NO;
    for (BBItem *itemB in localArray){
        if ([itemA.name isEqualToString:itemb.named]){
            there = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!there) {
         //add to a newItems array
    }
}
```

This is inefficient, because the inner loop goes through all items that you currently have. As the number of local items grows, this loop will get slower and slower. You would be better off maintaining an `NSMutableSet` of names of local items, because you can check it in constant, rather than in linear, time:

```
NSMutableSet *localNames = [NSMutableSet set];
for (BBItem *itemB in localArray) {
    [localNames addObject:itemB.name];
}
for (BBItem *itemA in serverDataArray){
    if (![localNames containsObject:itemA.name]) {
         //add to a newItems array
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. The data set generally won't be large. However, I am interested in making it more efficient. Could you tell me how exactly I would use NSMutableSet?

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Going to give it a try!